# How to replace matching string by its content in parentheses in shell

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to produce a shell script which is formatting commits in Shell.
After making a git log, I use grep to delete useless lines and now I want to change this :

`feat(my-feat): my commit`

to this:

`my-feat: my commit`

I want to write directly in a file: `git log ... | grep -v ... >> CHANGELOG.md`

Do you please have an idea how to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You may interest yourself in `sed`, but even two `cut`s will be enough.

Comment: Are you matching the literal string `feat`?  eg, `sed -e 's/feat(\([^)]*\))/\1/'`. Or are you looking to remove more generally? eg `sed -e '/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\))$/s//\1/'`. You need to give more precise details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to replace : feat(XXX):yyyy by XXX:yyyy, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^(]*(\([^)]*\))/\1/' input_file > new_file
$ cat new_file
my-feat: my commit
```

Comment: The only problem is that it's removing stars at the beginning of the line, I'm looking for a solution to that but thank you, it's helping me a lot. 

Edit: I found a solution and a useful site: sed.js.org , thanks again !

Comment: @Ams Can you provide a sample with the stars included? As in an actual representation of your data so I can try and provide a solution that works?

Comment: I already find what I wanted to do:


`sed 's/[^*  (]*(\([^)]*\))/**\1**/'`


I think that when it will be done I'll put it as opensource, it will be helpful I think.
Thanks a lot for your help !